# Posting message to multiple walls does not work

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, notifications, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm developing some application for the Facebook and iPhone.

User of our application would like to send to his friends notifications (only friends not other people), such as normal message. But the problem is that it’s the same message such as: "I would like to invite you to a party on Saturday". Posting one message works, but I encountered a problem when I post more messages at once. I do believe that this have to be some anti-spam filter or some other mechanism that is prohibiting posting messages in batch to walls of friends. I’m using Graph API for posting. Can somebody explain me or lead to some link how exactly this works and more importantly how to avoid this in my application…? Is it possible by paying some fee/credits to Facebook to allow my users to post messages to friends as they would like or this is simply not possible?

Just one important note: this is not a spam software and my user does not send wall messages (or notifications) to other people, only his selected friends and for sure the user is aware about this and the message is sent after user confirmation. Maybe I miss something, some application privilege?

Thank you in advance.

Marcin